# self and root in python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

As far as I know from the docs:
`self` - references to the current widget instance;
`root` - references to the root widget instance (top layout)

So I have tutorial Pong app.
Why do we use `self` in Rectangle parameters? `self` refers to current widget instance `Rectangle`, so when we write `size: 10, self.height`, doesn't it mean that Rectangle height equals Rectangle height?
Or what instance does this `self` refer to? Thanks.

Code .py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class PongGame(Widget):
    pass
class Grudget3App(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()
Grudget3App().run()
```

Code .kv:

```
<PongGame>
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x-5, 0
            size: 10, self.height
    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top -50
        text: "0"
    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3/4
        top: root.top -50
        text: "0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> self refers to current widget instance Rectangle

Rectangle is not a widget, it is a canvas instruction. `self` does refer to the current widget, which in your example is the `PongGame`.

Comment: Thanks. And what about Label? It is a widget, right? So when we use self inside Label it refers to Label instance?

Answer (score 0):

self always refers to the current widget , if you say size:self.size in your canvas it will take the size of your root widget. when you say root.something you refer top level properties of your widget eg.

main.kv

```
<BoxLayout>:
    
    text: '' # now you can use this is python as a stringproperty to change textinput

    TextInput:

            text:root.text
```